# Free XSL-FO to PDF converter besides Apache FOP

Tags: file-converter, pdf-generation

Is there any free software around besides Apache FOP to convert XSL-FO to PDF?

I have found FO.Net - however, the need for an extra runtime or an asp-aware web service does not appeal to me.

The software would not need to cover the XSL-FO standard completely but tables, lists, headers/footers ('regions'), and external graphics are a must. Projects in progress are fine.

I frankly did not take the time to check all commercial offers popping up whether they may be used for free with certain limitations in use or functionality, so hints to such solutions are welcome too. Whatever the limitations, usage must be free for an unlimited time and an unlimited number of pdf pages ( it is acceptable that there is a page limit for each invocation of the software).

A set of free tools that allows for a chained conversion with one or more interim representations would also be acceptable.

Comment: What problems do you have with Apache FOP?

Comment: My company's business software platform uses fop for db-driven report generation. There are occasional issues with user-supplied svgs referenced as external graphics in fo (I'd have to look up specifics), no fop would simplify deployments slightly, and we think of moving part of the report generation client-side.